# Homomorphism theorem and group product

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

I started studying group theory and I am puzzled about a manipulation of the homomorphism theorem.

It says:

$$G/{\ker}(\phi) \simeq {\rm im}(\phi)$$

but can it also imply:

$$ G = {\rm ker}(\phi) \times {\rm im}(\phi)$$

Is it always true for a finite group G and in which case is it true for infinite group G (if classifiable)?

Comment: No, it's not always true. For example, the homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Z_4 \to \Bbb Z_2$ given by $[k]_4 \mapsto [k]_2$ gives us that $\Bbb Z_4/2\Bbb Z_4 \cong \Bbb Z_2$, but $\Bbb Z_4 \not\cong \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: The first is not a division and so you cannot just cancel things out. There is a Theorem on how a group may be written as a direct product of its subgroups, you may need to check that those conditions are met

Comment: It can indeed emply that...but in general it does not, not even in the finite case. For one, $\;\text{Im}\,(\phi)\;$ is not usually even a subgroup of $\;G\;$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have dihedral group $D_3$ and $\phi=sgn$, then ${\rm im} \phi=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\ker \phi=\mathbb{Z}_3$ but

$$D_3 \neq \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Comment: Equivalently, $ S_3 \ne A_3 \times C_2$.